# Can someone give me an example of how a mousejoint works in libgdx?

Tags: box2d, libgdx, jbox2d

I have been banging my head against a brick wall for the past few hours.
I can't for the life of me get a mousejoint to work in the libgdx framework or java.
Could someone provide me with a quick example with sourcecode on how to use a mousejoint with libgdx? If not, with just Java?
Thanks

Comment: The jbox2d testbed example may be useful (look for the mouseDown function) http://code.google.com/p/jbox2d/source/browse/trunk/jbox2d-testbed/src/main/java/org/jbox2d/testbed/framework/TestbedTest.java

Answer (score 3):

You can download the whole libgdx trunk and take a look at the tests. For instance, check this one out:

[https://github.com/libgdx/../tests/Box2DTest.java](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/Box2DTest.java)

It uses a mouse joint to pick and drag a body.

Comment: +1 and I have one question: Does MouseJoint support 2 fingers? If yes, share a link, please.

Comment: I dont have an example... but I guess you'll just have to associate one joint to each finger (pointer). That should be easy...

Comment: Make a list of Joints, for each finger down add a new joint associated with one finger to the list, for each finger up delete the associated joint from the list.